# How to put name of every month before each value in list, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a program which calculates number of working hours for each month excluding weekends for this year

```
 M = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    mod_sums = [ (s - (s // 7) - ((s + 1) // 7)) * 8 for s in M]


    values = ' '.join(str(v) for v in mod_sums)
    print(values)
```

This is result of the code:

```
0 184 160 184 176 184 176 184 184 176 184 176 184
```

So now what I want to do is before every number I want it to show the name of the month so for example:

```
0 January = 184 February = 160 March = 184 etc, etc..
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use [Calendar API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) for this. `calendar.month_name[3]` would return `March`

Comment: Put the month names in another list, zip the two lists together in the list comprehension.

Comment: Why `0` in beginning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, Just create a list of months and simply join them,

```
In [18]: month_lst = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
    ...:               'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

In [20]: ' ,'.join(' = '.join(v) for v in zip(month_lst,map(str,mod_sums)))
Out[20]: 'January = 184 ,Feburary = 160 ,March = 184 ,April = 176 ,May = 184 ,June = 176 ,July = 184 ,August = 184 ,September = 176 ,October = 184 ,November = 176 ,December = 184'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calendar API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) to do this if you don't wish to create list of months manually. It will `calendar.month_name[i]` will outputs `January` if `i=0` and so on...

```
>>> import calendar
>>> M = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
>>> mod_sums = [ (s - (s // 7) - ((s + 1) // 7)) * 8 for s in M]
>>> values = str(mod_sums[0]) + " " + ' '.join("{} = {}".format(calendar.month_name[i], v) for i,v in enumerate(mod_sums[1:],start=1))
```

**Outputs**

```
>>> values
>>> '0 January = 184 February = 160 March = 184 April = 176 May = 184 June = 176 July = 184 August = 184 September = 176 October = 184 November = 176 December = 184'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a single for-loop, with the help of [Calendar API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name):

```
import calendar 

M = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

print(M[0], end=" ")  # For whatever reason you are printing this value

for i in range(1,len(M)):
    print(calendar.month_name[i],"=",(i - (i // 7) - ((i + 1) // 7)),end=" ")
```